# Reuse vector heap space for owned Cows without transmute?

Tags: rust

I am trying to optimize a Rust program through reduced allocations. I have many borrowed string slices that sometimes need to be turned into owned string slices. There is a function that takes in two `Vec`s of `Cow<str>` values, one of them `'static` (V1) and one `'_` (V2). I need to clear V2, then read the `'static` values from V1 and copy them into V2, returning a `Vec<Cow<'static, str>>`. This is problematic because the compiler thinks the lifetime of V2 is `'_` even though at runtime it will only hold values that are `'static`. I have presently made it work by using `transmute`, but transmuting to the static lifetime is a major code smell IMO. Here is a minimum example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn drain(owned: Vec<Cow<'static, str>>, mut borrowed: Vec<Cow<'_, str>>) -> Vec<Cow<'static, str>> {
    borrowed.clear();
    let mut out = unsafe {
        fn assert_static<T: 'static>(_x: &T) {}
        assert_static(&owned);

        std::mem::transmute::<Vec<Cow<'_, str>>, Vec<Cow<'static, str>>>(borrowed)
    };

    for v in owned {
        out.push(v);
    }

    out
}
```

Is it possible to write this function without any additional allocations and without using `transmute`?

Here are some alternatives that I've considered:

- Why not just return `owned`? In real code I do not add every element from `owned` to `out`, and I sometimes need to add in new elements in between the elements from `owned`.
- Why not `let mut out = Vec::with_capacity(owned.len())`? In my testing, this has a performance cost of around 0.8MiB/s. This represents an approximately 10% difference and I'd like to minimize runtime to the greatest extent possible.

Comment: Maybe after `borrow.clear()` try `borrowed.into_raw_parts()` and then use `Vec::from_raw_parts()`? Still unsafe, but I think that may be necessary using only the standard library, and certainly far better than transmute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to continue using `transmute` here, but I did isolate it to a single function which can be used in different contexts:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn clear_and_reinterpret<'a>(mut data: Vec<Cow<'_, str>>) -> Vec<Cow<'a, str>> {
    data.clear();

    unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<Vec<Cow<'_, str>>, Vec<Cow<'a, str>>>(data) }
}
```

I know that the turbofish on `transmute` is technically not required but it is best practice to include it due to how dangerous `transmute` is if used incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main question is "Do you really need this optimization?"

The difference will only matter if the function is called many times in a tight loop. If you don't have evidence that it matters, I suggest simply going with `owned.clone()` and be done with it. If you do have evidence that this is a performance bottleneck, using `transmute()` is fine and the right solution. The two types you are transmuting between are identical except for the lifetime, so there can't be any difference in memory layout, and it's easy to see that the new lifetime is fine. At the time of the transmutation the vector is empty anyway, and the new elements are added in safe code again.

As a side note, you don't really need `assert_static()`. The loop at the end of the function will fail if the item type of `owned` isn't static.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the original question, this has a performance bump of around 0.8 MiB/s, which is about a 10% difference in performance. I do agree on the `assert_static` being unnecessary though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Vec::into_raw_parts()`:

```rust
#![feature(vec_into_raw_parts)]

use std::borrow::Cow;

fn drain(owned: Vec<Cow<'static, str>>, mut borrowed: Vec<Cow<'_, str>>) -> Vec<Cow<'static, str>> {
    borrowed.clear();
    let (ptr, len, cap) = borrowed.into_raw_parts();
    let ptr = ptr as *mut u8 as *mut Cow<'static, str>;
    let mut borrowed: Vec<Cow<'static, str>> = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, cap) };
    borrowed.extend_from_slice(&owned);
    borrowed
}
```

(I'm not sure why the intermediate cast to `*mut u8` seems to be necessary, omitting it leads to what seems like a spurious error, E0621).

---

**Edit**: `Vec::into_raw_parts()` is unstable, but [its source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/497ee321af3b8496eaccd7af7b437f18bab81abf/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs#L716-L719) is simply:

```rust
pub fn into_raw_parts(self) -> (*mut T, usize, usize) {
    let mut me = ManuallyDrop::new(self);
    (me.as_mut_ptr(), me.len(), me.capacity())
}
```

Therefore, on stable, you can do:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;

fn drain(owned: Vec<Cow<'static, str>>, mut borrowed: Vec<Cow<'_, str>>) -> Vec<Cow<'static, str>> {
    borrowed.clear();
    let mut borrowed = ManuallyDrop::new(borrowed);
    let (ptr, len, cap) = (borrowed.as_mut_ptr(), borrowed.len(), borrowed.capacity());
    let ptr = ptr as *mut u8 as *mut Cow<'static, str>;
    let mut borrowed: Vec<Cow<'static, str>> = unsafe { Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, cap) };
    borrowed.extend_from_slice(&owned);
    borrowed
}
```

Comment: This would work, but I'd like to avoid using nightly features so I think I might be stuck with `transmute`

Comment: @LilyMara `Vec::into_raw_parts()` is really just syntax sugar for using `ManuallyDrop` and getting the parts individually, which you can already do manually on stable Rust. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Coder-256, but I think I'm going to stick with using `transmute`. `*mut T as *u8 as *mut U` is essentially the same as `transmute::<T, U>` but written with more code.

Comment: Ok. Since the lifetime is the only thing changing here, I agree that this may be one of the few valid uses of `transmute`.